# Hard java array situation

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am trying to compute this problem all day long and it seems i can't figure out how to do it:

```
List<ArrayList<Word>> words = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Word>>();
```

- words index 0 has : defin 3,countri 1,chairman 2,year 1,
- words index 1 has : defin 2,build 1,countri 1,round 3
- words index 2 has : cup 3,patent 1,round 2,year 2,

What I want to do is to find which words belong to other arrays and add their numbers together and then divide that with first occurrence.

For example:

- When index = 0 and word = defin -->  3/2+0
- When index = 0 and word = countri -->  1/1+0
- ....
- When index = 1 and word = defin -->  2/3+0
- When index = 1 and word = round -->  3/2+0
- ....
- When index = 2 and word = cup -->  3/0+0 but must do 3/1 so it wont "break".

Comment: you example is not clear. "When index = 0 and word = defin --> 3/2+0" i think i understand where the 3 comes from but why divide by 2 ? and why do you always add 0 ?

Comment: If I was doing this, I'd make my data structure `ArrayList<HashMap<String, Integer>> words = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Integer>>();` 
i.e. each of your lists would instead have a mapping of say `cup : 1, defin : 3` and it would be easier to find words that way instead of having to do string manipulation.

Comment: i divide by 2 because in the second array i.e when index is 1 defin is 2 ans on the third one is 0. Thats where 0s come

Comment: So can you get out arbitrary fractions from this?  Mapping into Integers might not be enough.

Comment: Rereading your example, I'm _really_ not clear on which numbers are being divided by what.  Much more detail would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks all for responding. In order to exactly understand what i want to do i will tell you what is my aim from this. 
I have 3 files which includes 4 rows each with 2 columns. Each row has the 'word' and the 'frequency'. I read all 3
files the contents are stored in an array of arrays. So i will have an array of size 3 (number of files) and then each 
position will have 4 elements. Each element is the word and along with its frequency.

Comment: Each file represents a category 
and the 4 most frequent words. So i need to calculate the possibility of a word belonging to a category. So if give to
the system a word it needs to go over the arrays find the word and calculate the possibility. 

In the example above, the word 'defin' has a possibility of 3/2+0 for the first category and 2/3+0 for the second. 0 for the third.
And so on for all.

Comment: ...Do you mean the probability?  Probabilities are always at most 1, which 3/2 is not.  Or perhaps the odds?

Comment: Well, yes your are right it's not exactly the probability that am after but in any way the higher the value the higher the probability of that word to belong to that category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it, not the best way in terms of efficiency but it works. In any way it is not efficiency that am after but rather to make it 'just work'.

So what i do is that i loop over the size of the first array and check whether the word belongs to any of the arrays or not. When i find that i store its frequency value. Then i go over the arrays again except for that that i have found the word the first place. I sum up all the frequencies and in the end i dived the first frequency but the summed up from the others.

Answer (score 1):

I'm tempted to suggest [Guava's](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) [Multiset](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multiset), which is typically used to track multiple occurrences of the same objects -- like a `Map<E, Integer>`, but with much less hassle.

```
 List<Multiset<String>> words;
 int index;

 Map<String, Double> ratios = Maps.newHashMap();
 for(Multiset.Entry<String> entry : words.get(index).entrySet()) {
   String word = entry.getElement();
   int wordCountIn0 = words.get(0).count(word);
   if (wordCountIn0 == 0) wordCountIn0 = 1;
   ratios.put(word, (double) entry.getCount() / wordCountIn0);
 }
```

I'm not 100% clear on your problem, but as best as I understand it, this should work.

Comment: Hmm, i cannot really understand with this how to set the words and the frequencies for each word. Can you explain it a bit? thanks

Comment: If you're going through a document and adding one occurrence of each word, just use `multiset.add(word)` to add one occurrence of `word`.  If you want to set a count to an exact value, use `multiset.setCount(word, count)`.

Comment: The Multiset Javadoc is at http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html , which may help.

Comment: Thanks for your response, however i found another way to do it. Not the most optimum but it works. I will post the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate your data inside a class that maintains all pertinent data in various data stores.

Then query via that object. Think of it as a databse - you have the core data, but you also have things like indexes and views that present that data in a given way according to your usage requirements.

Comment: I already have a class Word which has the string of the word along with the frequency. My array list is the indexes so i think that there is not really a point to encapsulate more, or it is?